# What does the sticky bit do on files?(FreeBSD)

Tags: unix, permissions, freebsd

I know the sticky bit on directories allows file deletion only by the owner of files contained inside the sticky dir.

But I can also `chmod 1777` a File and the `ls -l` cmd shows that the file indeed has the sticky bit set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing.

From the docs: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sticky&sektion=7&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+10.3-RELEASE+and+Ports

> A special file mode, called the sticky bit    (mode S_ISTXT), is used to
>   indicate special treatment    for directories.  **It is   ignored for regular
>   files**.  See chmod(2) or the file  for an explanation of file
>   modes.

Erik Bennett linked the [Wikipedia article on the history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit#History) of the sticky bit - its original purpose was a hint to the kernel to try to keep files hot in swap, for performance. Modern OSs have abandoned this feature though.

> When set, it instructed the operating system to retain the text segment of the program in swap space after the process exited. This speeds up subsequent executions by allowing the kernel to make a single operation of moving the program from swap to real memory.
>
> One notable problem with "stickied" programs was replacing the executable (for instance, during patching); to do so required removing the sticky bit from the executable, executing the program and exiting to flush the cache, replacing the binary executable, and then restoring the sticky bit.
>
> Currently, this behavior is only operative in HP-UX and UnixWare. Solaris appears to have abandoned this in 2005. The 4.4-Lite release of BSD retained the old sticky bit behavior, but it has been subsequently dropped from OpenBSD (as of release 3.7) and FreeBSD (as of release 2.2.1). No version of Linux has ever supported this traditional behavior.